# Jquery - changing checkbox value depending on option from Dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I want to create a form whereby, when a user selects an option from a  dropdown list, certain items of a checkbox is checked.

http://jsfiddle.net/qNMAk/1/

i have started it here, no idea on how to implement it.

Comment: How do you know which checkboxes relate to which select options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to approach this but I would recommend setting the "class" of the checkboxes to the option values.  Then you could use jQuery like this:

```
$("select[name='types']").change(function() {
    // Get the value selected (convert spaces to underscores for class selection)
    var value = $(this).val().replace(' ', '_');

    // Clear checks, then check boxes that have class "value"
    $(":checkbox").prop("checked",false).filter("."+value).prop("checked",true);
});
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NEESR/)

Answer (score 0):

You could start using the `change()` event of `<select>` and then something like this:

```
$('select').change(function(){
    switch($(this).val()) {
        case 'Wedding':
            $('#checkbox').prop('checked', true);
            break;
        case 'Birthday':
            // something
            break;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

in some way you will have to relate the checkboxes to the select list value, if you modify your markup to give name of the checkbox equal to the select values

```
<select name="types">
<option value="Wedding">Wedding</option>
<option value="Birthday">Birthday</option>
<option value="Health Day">Health Day</option>
<option value="Custom Event">Custom</option>
</select>
<br/><br/><br/>
<fieldset>
    <h3><span>1</span>Entertainment:</h3>    
       <input type="checkbox" name="Wedding" value="Wedding" /> DJ<br />
       <input type="checkbox" name="Birthday" value="Birthday" /> Birthday<br />          
</fieldset>
```

jquery part

```
$("select").change(function(e){
    $(":checkbox").prop("checked",false); //de-select all the checkboxes
var v = $(this).val();
    $(":checkbox[name='"+v+"']").prop("checked",true);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/qNMAk/4/)

sure there are several ways to implement this scenario, but this demo will get you started

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use the [custom data attribute: (data-*)](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/alpacalips/qNMAk/5/)

```
<select name="types">
     <option value="">Select</option>
     <option value="wedding">Wedding</option>
     <option value="birthday">Birthday</option>
     <option value="health_day">Health Day</option>
     <option value="custom_event">Custom</option>
</select>

<input type="checkbox" name="entertainment" data-evt="custom_event" value="dj" /> DJ<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="entertainment" data-evt="birthday" value="Magician" /> Magician<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="entertainment" data-evt="custom_event" value="liveband" /> Live Music 
...
```

jquery

```
$('select').change(function(){
    var $evt = $(this).val(); // get type of event
    $(':input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false); // clear
    $(':input[data-evt="' + $evt + '"]').prop('checked', true); // Set check
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind the checkboxes with each dropdown options somehow. One possible solution would be to add `data` attribute to each option and selecting checkboxes based on that.

```
<select name="types">
<option value="Wedding" data='dj,singer,wedding,lighting'>Wedding</option>
<option value="Birthday" data='singer,lighting'>Birthday</option>
<option value="Health Day" data='comedian,magician,outdoor'>Health Day</option>
<option value="Custom Event">Custom</option>
</select>

$('select').change(function () {
    $('input:checkbox').attr('checked', false);
    var arrData = $('option:selected', this).attr('data').split(',');
    for (i in arrData) {
        $("input[value='" + arrData[i] + "']").attr('checked', true);
    }
}).change();
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/qNMAk/6/